# append sequence number with padded zeroes to a series using padas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                        'login_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM']})
df.login_date = pd.to_datetime(df.login_date)
df['logout_date'] = df.login_date + pd.Timedelta(days=5)
df['login_id'] = [1,1,1,1,8,8,8]
```

As you can see in the sample dataframe, the `login_id` is the same even though `login` and `logout` dates are different for the person.

For example, `person = 101`, has logged in and out at 4 different timestamps. but he has got the same login_ids which is incorrect.

Instead, I would like to generate a `new login_id` column where each person gets a new login_id but retains the `1st login_id` information in their subsequent logins. So, we can know its a sequence

I tried the below but it doesn't work well

```
df.groupby(['person_id','login_date','logout_date'])['login_id'].rank(method="first", ascending=True) + 100000
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below. You can see how `1` and `8`, the 1st login_id for each person is retained in their subsequent `login_ids`. We just add a sequence by adding `00001` and plus one based on number of rows.

Please note I would like to apply this on a big data and the `login_ids` may not just be `single digit` in real data. For ex, 1st login_id could even be `576869578` etc kind of random number. In that case, the subsequent login id will be `57686957800001`. Hope this helps. Whatever is the 1st `login_id` for that subject, add `00001`, `00002` etc based on the number of rows that person has. Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:** Just realized my previous answers also added 100000 to the first index. Here is a version that uses [**`GroupBy.transform()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to add 100000 only to subsequent indexes:

```py
cumcount = df.groupby(['person_id','login_id']).login_id.cumcount()
df.login_id = df.groupby(['person_id','login_id']).login_id.transform(
    lambda x: x.shift().mul(100000).fillna(x.min())
).add(cumcount)

    person_id           login_date          logout_date  login_id
# 0       101  2013-05-07 09:27:00  2013-05-12 09:27:00         1
# 1       101  2013-09-08 11:21:00  2013-09-13 11:21:00    100001
# 2       101  2014-06-06 08:00:00  2014-06-11 08:00:00    100002
# 3       101  2014-06-06 05:00:00  2014-06-11 05:00:00    100003
# 4       202  2011-12-11 10:00:00  2011-12-16 10:00:00         8
# 5       202  2012-10-13 00:00:00  2012-10-18 00:00:00    800001
# 6       202  2012-12-13 11:45:00  2012-12-18 11:45:00    800002
```

---

**Update:** Faster option is to build the sequence with [**`GroupBy.cumcount()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```py
cumcount = df.groupby(['person_id','login_id']).login_id.cumcount()
df.login_id = df.login_id.mul(100000).add(cumcount)

#   person_id           login_date          logout_date  login_id
# 0       101  2013-05-07 09:27:00  2013-05-12 09:27:00    100000
# 1       101  2013-09-08 11:21:00  2013-09-13 11:21:00    100001
# 2       101  2014-06-06 08:00:00  2014-06-11 08:00:00    100002
# 3       101  2014-06-06 05:00:00  2014-06-11 05:00:00    100003
# 4       202  2011-12-11 10:00:00  2011-12-16 10:00:00    800000
# 5       202  2012-10-13 00:00:00  2012-10-18 00:00:00    800001
# 6       202  2012-12-13 11:45:00  2012-12-18 11:45:00    800002
```

---

You can build the sequence in a [**`GroupBy.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```py
df.login_id = df.groupby(['person_id','login_id']).login_id.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series([x.min()*100000+seq for seq in range(len(x))], x.index)
)
```

Comment: Just wanna check. This will not clash with any of the other existing ids. Am I right? Because we are multplying all ids by a specific value like `100000` in your 2nd approach. There will be no clash between ids. Am I right?

Comment: While answer under `update` works faster on big data, when I try `update2` answer, it fails with memory error.

Comment: This is the new related post which I created. Can have a look at this and provide your answer please if you have time?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172115/generate-a-sequence-by-appending-values-without-clash-in-other-values

Comment: @TheGreat i will take a look later

Answer (score 1):

```
login_id = df.groupby('person_id').login_id.apply(list)
def modify_id(x):
    result= []
    for index,value in enumerate(x):
        if index > 0:
            value = (int(value) * 100000) + index
        result.append(value)
    return result

df['ogin_id'] = login_id.apply(lambda x : modify_id(x)).explode().to_list()
```

Will give output -

| person_id | login_date | logout_date | login_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2013-05-07 09:27:00 | 2013-05-12 09:27:00 | 1 |
| 101 | 2013-09-08 11:21:00 | 2013-09-13 11:21:00 | 100001 |
| 101 | 2014-06-06 08:00:00 | 2014-06-11 08:00:00 | 100002 |
| 101 | 2014-06-06 05:00:00 | 2014-06-11 05:00:00 | 100003 |
| 202 | 2011-12-11 10:00:00 | 2011-12-16 10:00:00 | 8 |
| 202 | 2012-10-13 00:00:00 | 2012-10-18 00:00:00 | 800001 |
| 202 | 2012-12-13 11:45:00 | 2012-12-18 11:45:00 | 800002 |

Comment: Hi, I get the below error `TypeError: explode() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`...

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of your original `rank()`

```py
df['login_id'] = df['login_id'] * 100000 + df.groupby(['person_id'])['login_id'].rank(method="first") - 1
```

```
# print(df)
   person_id          login_date         logout_date  login_id
0        101 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-05-12 09:27:00  100000.0
1        101 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2013-09-13 11:21:00  100001.0
2        101 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-11 08:00:00  100002.0
3        101 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-11 05:00:00  100003.0
4        202 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-16 10:00:00  800000.0
5        202 2012-10-13 00:00:00 2012-10-18 00:00:00  800001.0
6        202 2012-12-13 11:45:00 2012-12-18 11:45:00  800002.0
```

Then changed the first row of each group

```py
def change_first(group):
    group.loc[group.index[0], 'login_id'] = group.iloc[0]['login_id'] / 100000
    return group

df['login_id'] = df.groupby(['person_id']).apply(lambda group: change_first(group))['login_id']
```

```
# print(df)

   person_id          login_date         logout_date  login_id
0        101 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-05-12 09:27:00       1.0
1        101 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2013-09-13 11:21:00  100001.0
2        101 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-11 08:00:00  100002.0
3        101 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-11 05:00:00  100003.0
4        202 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-16 10:00:00       8.0
5        202 2012-10-13 00:00:00 2012-10-18 00:00:00  800001.0
6        202 2012-12-13 11:45:00 2012-12-18 11:45:00  800002.0
```

Or make use of `where()` to only update the row where condition is False.

```py
df_ = df['login_id'] * 100000 + df.groupby(['person_id'])['login_id'].rank(method="first") - 1

firsts = df.groupby(['person_id']).head(1).index

df['login_id'] = df['login_id'].where(df.index.isin(firsts), df_)
```