# Generate a sequence by appending values without clash in other values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                        'login_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM']})
df.login_date = pd.to_datetime(df.login_date)
df['logout_date'] = df.login_date + pd.Timedelta(days=5)
df['login_id'] = [1,1,1,1,11,11,11]
```

If you look at `person_id = 101` in the above dataframe, he/she has logged in and out at 4 different timestamps but have the same login_ids which is incorrect.

Instead, I would like to generate a new login_id for each unique login session where each person gets a new login_id but retains the 1st login_id information in their subsequent logins. So, we can know its a sequence

I tried the below (based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042817/append-sequence-number-with-padded-zeroes-to-a-series-using-padas))

```
cumcount = df.groupby(['person_id','login_id']).login_id.cumcount()
df.login_id = df.login_id.mul(100000).add(cumcount)
```

While the above does work fine for a given sample dataset, but it may fail when there is an actual matching login_id `1100001`, `1100002`, `1100003`. So, if I append `00001`, `00002` to my `login_id = 11`, it may clash with original ids `(1100001`, `1100002`, `1100003)`

We don't necessarily have to append only zeroes to indicate sequence. Any number that doesn't clash with other ids is fine (and it doesn't have to be in order like one after the other). We just need to get some id which doesn't clash with other ids

How can I generate a random number to indicate login_id without clashing with other login_ids from other users? how can I decide on the numbers to append?

Please note I would like to apply this on a big data and the login_ids may not just be single digit in real data. For ex, 1st login_id could even be 576869578 etc kind of random number.

Comment: If you don't have any rule for these ids, then there is no way to do what you ask.  You need a guaranteed safe number space.  Could you use negative numbers?

Comment: Do you think it is possible to get the maximum value (of login_id) from the dataframe and append as many zeroes to original_login_id? If the max (login_id) = 98765432. I know that I can append 8 zeroes to my login_ids.

Comment: if the first login must keep?if that's you need.could you use string like `login_id#seq`.if you do not need keep the first login id.could it be something like `user_id000seq`

Comment: Is `login_id` supposed to be a number or could it be a string too? Because if it could be a string, you could append the md5 hash or base64 of the `login_date` to the `login_id` to generate a unique id. Another approach could be to add a separator between the login_id and the subsequent number so instead of `1100001`, you would generate `11-00001` and that way to it won't clash with any other ids.

Comment: @AKS - Login_id has to be a number

Comment: Maybe you can create another column to store the login_id_seq.

Comment: @Ferris Unfortunately cannot.

Comment: I updated the question. It doesn't have to be a sequence. At least it can be some random number which doesn't clash with other existing ids. As long as different login sessions, have different login_ids, it should be fine...

Comment: use login_date timestamp format `1624943463 * 1000 + seq 0 ~ 999 if with same timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried appending zeroes based on the length of the dataframe to avoid any clash with existing ids. Any suggestions to improve this solution is welcome. This works on small data but fails on larger dataframe

```
cumcount = df.groupby(['person_id','login_id']).login_id.cumcount()
df.login_id = df.groupby(['person_id','login_id']).login_id.transform(lambda x: x.shift().mul(int('1'+'0'*(len(str(len(df)))+1))).fillna(x.min())).add(cumcount)
```

I don;t think the ids will clash now. Any suggestions or advice?

The output looks like as below

[image]